# My toilets are filling with HOT HOT Water and we have no water pressure

Tags: bathroom

Please help. We just rented this house and now realize why the walk through was so quick. Most important concern is that the toilets are filling with hot water!! ( In addition matter bath runs constantly, I just bought a new stopper last night, which should fix running water) we have NO WATER PRESSURE.  The owner told us as far as maintenance for us to take care of small things ourselves, but if something more serious his responsibility.

Comment: Welcome to DIYSE. Please revise your question to reduce it to one issue. [Take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand why if you're not familiar with our format. We're not a discussion forum. Post additional questions if you like. Thanks!

Comment: And toilets being plumbed to the hot water line doesn't fall under the category of "small things", to my mind.

Comment: Are you getting cold water out of other faucets--kitchen faucet, bathroom lavatory, tub or shower?

Comment: I had a house that got new water lines put in underneath house. The plumber got confused at laundry room and crossed the connections. Hot to cold cold to hot it happens

Answer (score 4):

Plumbing issues are not small things and should be the responsibility of the landlord.

It sounds like there is a  toilet [mixing valve](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BQMKCY) that has failed or was installed improperly.   In  places where the water supply is very cold  a mixing valve is used to  take the chill off of the water going to the tank to eliminate condensation on the size of the tank.

It is possible that the mixing valve was not set properly and that you could adjust the screw that regulates the amount of hot water mixing with the Cold water.

If you can locate the mixing valve that is a simple fix that you could take care of yourself anything else I would inform the landlord that it is their responsibility to remedy the situation.  The valve is usually located in an accessible place such as the crawlspace under the house or in the mechanical room where the hot water heater is  or it is possible  but not probable that there is an access panel on the backside of the wall that the toilet sits against.

If your mixing valve is like the one that I linked to there is a screw adjustment on  One side of the  valve that can be adjusted with a slotted screwdriver, screwing it in reduces the amount of hot water aloud through the valves.

If it is a mixing valve issue I don’t think that would account for the lack of water pressure. That is something that is certainly going to have to be addressed by a professional plumber.

Is the water pressure issue a problem with all of your Faucets or just the toilet?

Comment: Guess it takes an Alaskan man to know such a device as a toilet mixing valve exists.  Being from the south, I've never run into one.

Comment: Yes we ( on the  anchorage muni water system ) drink ice cold tap water from a glacier fed lake and it is great. long ago I lived on the anchorage hillside and had water from a well that tapped into an aquifer that was fed by a glacier ice field, the best water i have ever had.

Comment: The water pressure  is not good in the kitchen as well, thank you so much for your response. So very helpful. I'm going into the access panel, now that I know what to look for